# AzureML experiment pipeline not using CUDA with PyTorch

Tags: azure, pytorch, azure-machine-learning-service, azureml-python-sdk

I am running an experiment pipeline to train my model with PyTorch and CUDA.
I created the environment as follow:

```py
    env = Environment.from_conda_specification(model, join(model, 'conda_dependencies.yml'))
    env.docker.enabled = True
    env.environment_variables = {'MODEL_NAME': model, 'BRANCH': branch, 'COMMIT': commit}
    env.docker.base_image = DEFAULT_GPU_IMAGE

    run_config = RunConfiguration()
    run_config.environment = env
    run_config.docker = DockerConfiguration(use_docker=True)
```

And here is the training step:

```py
train_step = PythonScriptStep(
      name='Model Train',
      source_directory=training_dir,
      compute_target=cluster,
      runconfig=run_config,
      script_name='train_aml.py',
      arguments=[
        '--model', model,
        '--model_output_dir', model_output_dir,
      ],
      inputs=[train_dataset.as_mount()],
      outputs=[model, model_output_dir]
    )
```

Even though I am using a `Standard_NC12_Promo` machine when I run my training script, the GPU is not picked up by PyTorch `device = torch.device("cuda" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")`.
If I try running my script on the same machine but not in an experiment then the GPU is used.
Do you know any potential solutions to this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on pytorch version you might need a specific version of cuda. Try cuda 11.0.3 or cuda 11.1 from here
https://github.com/Azure/AzureML-Containers/tree/master/base/gpu

Regarding your code snippet, please move environment variables out of environment object to runconfiguration

Comment: Seems CUDA is not picked up by the container for some reasons. A solution maybe is to get a curated env and brute-force install some dependencies. Where do you suggest I should insert the environment variables? The runconfig has no environment variable property.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.runconfig.runconfiguration?view=azure-ml-py#variables

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue. An experiment that just did `torch.cuda.device_count()` returned the right number of GPUs, but `torch.cuda.is_available()` returned `False`.

It turned out that the problem was with the CUDA toolkit version. Here's how I debugged it.

1. Fire up your compute instance
2. Go to notebooks and click the Open Terminal button (yellow here) [image]
3. Type in `nvidia-smi`
4. Look at the CUDA version like in this image [image]
5. Make sure that your environment image is using the same or lower CUDA version. For example, I downgraded mine from 11.7 to 11.1.
6. Run the same experiment as above, the `torch.cuda.is_available()` should be `True` now.
7. Run a real experiment - it worked for me.

Cheers!